# Get total when type on a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, int, calculation

I have two textFields and i want to get total of both textFields into a Text using Flutter.
I tried several ways but I don't know how to do it,

I have number of textFields and it changes according to my List "letter", So how can i get the total of all these textFields that appear?

```
List letter;
int letterCount = 0;
int letterCount2 = 0;

for(int count; count<(letters.length); count++){
  TextField(
     onChanged: (text) {
     setState(){
        letterCount = int.parse(text);
     }
  },
}
Text(
     'Total - $letterCount2',
)
```

This code doesn't work accurately and I also want to work it if i backspace the answer or change it
If someone can help me to go through this it would be great :)

Comment: Try to use a statefull widget and define three variables as part of your state assign the two fields as values to the two texfields and the third one to your text, and all the time those textfields changes perform a setState with the calculation you wish to perform. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it worked
But I had to change my code; I uploaded the new code so it's hard to get the total now, please check. Thanks!

Comment: why not use `ListView.builder` method to create the no. of textfield widgets according to the length of variable letter. that's what you are trying to do here right?

Comment: and you should use `letterCount2 += int.parse(text);`  so that the count in the variable will be updated.

Comment: Ah yeah
thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your calculatuions into setState so that the app re-draws to show updated total:

```
  int letterCount = 0;
  int letterCount2 = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
            letterCount = int.parse(text);
          });
        },
      ),
      TextField(
        onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
            letterCount2 = letterCount + (int.parse(text));
          });
        },
      ),
      Text(
        'Total - $letterCount2',
      ),
    ]));
  }
```

Comment: Yes it worked
But I had to change my code; I uploaded the new code so it's hard to get the total now, please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not able to see the changes in the output if you are using `stateless` widget

Try using `Statefull` widget

and whenever you want the ui to update make sure you are calling `setState` method

try below shown code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              letterCount = int.parse(text);
            });
          }),
          TextField(onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              letterCount2 = letterCount + (int.parse(text));
            });
          }),
          Text('Total - $letterCount2')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //declare your variables.
  int letterCount = 0;
  int letterCount2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked
But I had to change my code; I uploaded the new code so it's hard to get the total now, please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like you and the others did, changing the first TextField won't change the result. I would do it like this:

```
int letterCount = 0;
int letterCount2 = 0;

TextField(
    onChanged: (text) {
      setState(() {
          letterCount = int.parse(text);
      });
},
TextField(
    onChanged: (text) {
      setState(() {
          letterCount2 = int.parse(text);
      });
},
Text(
    'Total - ${letterCount + letterCount2}',
)
```

Don't forget to wrap it all in a StatefulWidget, otherwise the setState function won't work.

Comment: Yes it worked
But I had to change my code; I uploaded the new code so it's hard to get the total now, please check. Thanks!